# Why the cost of assignment is not guaranteed to be less than a constructor-destructor pair?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, assignment-operator

In Scott Meyers's "Effective C++" Item 26: Postpone variable definitions as long as possible, the cost of an assignment is not surely less than a constructor-destructor pair.

Then,for different data types or classes, how can I compare the cost of an assignment with a constructor-destructor pair?Which one will be cheaper and why?

In my opinion,constructor-destructor pair need to allocate and deallocate memory,and constructor at least will initialize the variable. But assignment only needs to change the value of variable.

So, I think generally the cost of assignment should be less than a constructor-destructor pair.

Comment: Who says constructors always need to allocate memory? How do you guarantee that changing the value of an `int` costs less than constructing an `int`? If you can't guarantee that for an `int`, how do you guarantee it for a simple type with an `int` member?

Comment: If you create an object inside a function, return it, and then either A) assign it to an existing variable or B) construct a new variable from it, then B) might be faster because of the return value optimization.

Comment: "*constructor-destructor pair need to allocate and deallocate memory*" Why do you say that? Why would, for example, an [RAII lock holder](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) need any memory allocated?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429460/should-one-keenly-consciously-attempt-to-postpone-variable-definitions-as-long

Comment: Oh,I see.But for classes that need to allocate memory,what will happen?@David Schwartz@JonathanWakely

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the advice. The recommendation is saying it is cheaper to do "construction + destruction" than "default construction + assignment + destruction".

In any case, it's not guaranteed that assignment is cheaper, that's up to the class author. Not all constructors allocate memory, and not all assignments simply "change the value of variable", some assignments re-allocate, or perform non-trivial checks on the value. Also, some assignments are implemented in terms of construction+destruction, as in the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
T& operator=(const T& t) {
  T(t).swap(*this);
  return *this;
}
```

This assignment is certainly not cheaper than construction, because it does construction+swap+destruction.

Comment: Could you please tell me when will assignment cheaper than construction-destruction or vise versa?@Jonathan Wakely

Comment: I already showed an example where assignment is more expensive. It's cheaper when it doesn't do more work. There are countless possible examples.